# Version of Farkas lemma on Modified Set

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

So the question is framed like this,

Let $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a convex set and $D = \{Fu+g | u \in \mathbb{R}^{m}\}$, where $F \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$, and $g \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ are fixed and $u$ is a free variable . Also $C \cap D = \varnothing$.

Show that there exist $\lambda \neq 0$ such that $F^{T}\lambda = 0$ and $\lambda^{T}x \leq \lambda^{T}g$, $\forall x \in C$.

$\textit{Solution}$
I have three things which I think are helpful,

1. From linear algebra: $c^{T}x = d$ for all x satisfying Ax = b if and only if there is a vector $\lambda$ such that $c = A^{T}\lambda, d = b^{T}\lambda$.
2. By separating hyperplanes theorem between two convex sets $C_1$ and $C_2$, which are disjoint, there exists a vector $a\neq0$ such that $a^{T}x_{1} \leq a^{T}x_{2}$  for every $x_{1} \in C_1, x_{2} \in C_2$.
3. $\lambda^{T}x \leq \lambda^{T}(Fu+g)$, $\forall x \in C$.

I have thought of numerous ways to solve but end up failing, can anybody help or provide hints?

Thanks

Comment: What is $\Phi$? the empty set? (2) would be the way to go. The definition of $D$ is strange: as written $D=\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Yes $\Phi$ is empty set.

Comment: There was a mistake I have corrected the question

Comment: I would suspect that the matrix $F$ and the vector $g$ are fixed.

Comment: Yes they are fixed and u is free variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be safe, we should assume that $C$ is nonempty.  You can indeed show this using the hyperplane separation theorem. Let $\lambda \neq 0$ be such that $\lambda^T x_1 \leq \lambda^T x_2$ for every $x_1 \in C$ and $x_2 \in D$. In other words, $\lambda^T x_1 \leq \lambda^T(Fu + g)$ for every $x_1 \in C$ and $u \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

If $\lambda^TF = 0$ then we are done (why?). Assume for contradiction that $\lambda^T F = a^T \neq 0$. Then you can find some vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $a^Tv < 0$ (how?). But now for a scalar $k > 0$ we have $$\lambda^T(F(kv) + g) = ka^Tv + \lambda^Tg$$ which tends to $-\infty$ as we increase $k$. On the other hand, the above should be bounded from below by $\lambda^T x_1$ for any $x_1 \in C$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Hi, this clears everything. Thank you soo much. Juts one last thing can we use the above results to prove a variant of Farkas lemma i.e., ${x | Ax \leq b}$ is empty $\iff \exists \lambda \geq 0$ s,t, $\lambda^{T}A = 0, \lambda^{T}b<0$

Comment: can you help in above comment

Comment: With a bit of work, yes. Note that $\{x: Ax \leq b\}$ being empty means precisely that $C = \{x: x \leq 0\}$ and $D = \{Ax - b : x \in \mathbb{R}^m\}$ have empty intersection. Sadly, applying the above result to this won't quite work. Instead, you should show that $C_\varepsilon\ = \{x : x \leq \varepsilon \cdot \underline1\}$ also has empty intersection with $D$ for small enough $\varepsilon$, and use the result for these sets.

Comment: Hi @Daniel, are you sure that set C  = $\{ x: x <0\}$, $\lambda^{T}b <0$ only if x>0. Can you help?